# Short story collection: starts out with alien talking about his giant ship they built

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

Their planet is dying or something and they all go in different directions, and he crash-lands on Earth on a farm I think. His ship is about the size of a bowling ball to us, and he's the size of an insect. He's exploring the area when a human picks him up, and he uses his laser on the human but the human just thinks it's a bug bite and squashes him.

I think it was like he was writing in a "captain's log" sort of thing.

It was a paperback, I can't remember if it was the first story of the collection but I think it was more in the middle of the book, and I thought they were all the same author but now I'm not sure. I thought it was Asimov but now I'm not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out! It was ["Meteor"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?69109) (1941) by [John Wyndham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wyndham), in the short story collection [*The Seeds of Time*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?46810).

From [SittingBee](http://sittingbee.com/meteor-john-wyndham/):

> In Meteor by John Wyndham we have the theme of hope, connection, destruction, acceptance and loss. Narrated using a dual narrative of both a third person human narrator and a first person alien (Onns) narrator the reader realises after reading the story that Wyndham may be exploring the theme of hope. Onns through his journal writes about the hopes and aspirations of the people of Forta. Their own world is dying and they hope to be able to continue living in other parts of the universe. In Onns case he is hoping to assimilate with life on Earth. If anything Onns wishes to make a connection with those who live on Earth. **However any type of assimilation is hampered by the physical size of Onns. Onns is less than a quarter of an inch in height and is viewed upon by Graham as being more like an ant than an intelligent life form from another plant or galaxy.**