# Short story - 60s or earlier - meteorite is actually crashed alien ship full of tiny insect-sized beings

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, spaceship

This story was in one of the first SF anthologies I ever read, in the mid-1960s. A meteor lands near to a house. The householder finds it and carries it into his house (meteor is grapefruit/football sized). It’s actually a crashed spaceship, crewed by beings the size of beetles or cockroaches.

They emerge, and are spotted by the householder, who of course thinks they’re insects, but notices one seems to be holding a tiny tube. He reaches towards it and the alien shoots his hand (the tube being a gun, of course), stinging him.

I can’t recall how the story ends, but I’d love to know what the story was called, and who its author was, as I’m trying to assemble a list of the early SF that fired my enthusiasm for the genre.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short story collection: starts out with alien talking about his giant ship they built](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137935/short-story-collection-starts-out-with-alien-talking-about-his-giant-ship-they)

Comment: @BjornEriksson No confirmed answer here so not a dupe.

Comment: There's a similar story, sadly I forget the author, in which the alien insect-things are crystalline based, and they (and their meteorite spaceship) are all destroyed by an audiophile who finds the resonant frequency and blasts his speakers at them.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is surely "[Meteor](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?69109)", a short story by John Wyndham. Under the pseudonym "John Benyon" and the alternate title "Phoney Metor", this appeared in *Amazing Stories*, March 1941, and is readable at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/amazing-stories-v-15-n-03-1941-03/page/96/mode/2up).

As you say, a spaceship carrying tiny aliens, looking for a new world to colonise, crashes into a homeowner's garden. They carry it into their shed:

> They all went into the outhouse, which was built of brick, with a
> floor of wooden boards. The meteor lay in the middle of the floor. It
> was less than a metre in diameter, and looked like an ordinary ball of
> metal.

The aliens have various adventures, fighting against insects and spiders as they explore the interior of the shed. Eventually they come across a pet dog, and shoot it dead with their ray guns. Sally, the dog's owner, comes to see what happened

> She went down on her knees beside the dog’s body. "She is dead!" she
> said. "I wonder what " She suddenly stood up, put her hand to her leg,
> and held it tight. `Oh, something has stung me. Oh, it hurts." There
> were tears of pain in her eyes as she rubbed her leg
>
> "What on earth−?" began her father, looking down at the dog. "What are
> all those things? Ants?"

The aliens "sting" (i.e. shoot) the father too, so he gets some insecticide and spreads it over them.

> The three people watched as the little creatures crawled more and more
> slowly. Some of them turned over, weakly waving their legs in the air.
> Then they lay still.
>
> "We won’t have any more trouble from them," Graham said. "Horrible
> little creatures! I’ve nevers een anything like them − I wonder what
> on earth they were?"

Answer (score 3):

["Meteor"](https://englishlanguageliterature.wordpress.com/2011/09/02/meteor-by-john-wyndham/) by John Wyndham has a similar theme.